# How can I insert image in Access table

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, oledb

I want to insert image in access table. I have all records in DataTable object which is id, name, city, photo etc. Now I want to insert these records in access table.

I am using c# as programing language and .net framework 3.5.

Thanks.

Comment: Access table or Access database ......?

Comment: What have you tried already? Where did you stuck? I guess you didnt tried to google at all...

Comment: I had google it. And also access table have image datatype. Problem is that whole records is inside datatable object and they can vary. I have ti insert record from datatable to access table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this should help

```
var oleDbConnection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\sample.accdb");
var oleDbCommand = oleDbConnection.CreateCommand();
oleDbCommand.CommandText = "insert into Table1 (Name, Photo) values (@name, @photo)";
oleDbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "MyName");
byte[] yourPhoto = GetYourPhotoFromSomewhere();
oleDbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@photo", yourPhoto);
using (oleDbConnection)
{
    oleDbConnection.Open();
    oleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[This article on MSDN Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/c3fae255-9d2e-45e9-b830-58d544fc43ee/) shows how to read and write image data in MS ACCESS.

You will have to use **Image** data type for the photo field. While inserting convert the data into byte array and pass as parameters.